# Mysql update if (some statement)

Tags: mysql, count

I wanna create a mysql update only if the table does not contain the specified value(if player have empty slot)

My Idea:

```
update player_items 
set slot=20 
where id=0 
and uid=2 
and (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM player_items 
     WHERE slot=12 and uid=2) = 0;
```

[code in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f48/1)

I hope this can be only one mysql question

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using the anti-join pattern, e.g.

```
UPDATE player_items p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT uid
           FROM player_items
          WHERE slot = 12
            AND uid = 2
          LIMIT 1
       ) q
    ON q.uid = p.uid
   SET p.slot = 20
 WHERE p.id = 0
   AND p.uid = 2
   AND q.uid IS NULL
```

The LEFT JOIN looks for a matching row, but if no matching row is found then MySQL will generate a row with all NULL values. We can filter out any rows that matched using the `q.uid IS NULL` predicate, so we will only get rows where there was no match.

```
mysql> UPDATE player_items p
    ->   LEFT
    ->   JOIN ( SELECT uid
    ->            FROM player_items
    ->           WHERE slot = 12
    ->             AND uid = 2
    ->           LIMIT 1
    ->        ) q
    ->     ON q.uid = p.uid
    ->    SET p.slot = 20
    ->  WHERE p.id = 0
    ->    AND p.uid = 2
    ->    AND q.uid IS NULL
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: spencer7593 this not works :( I got an error in my mysql and SQL Fiddle (Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE player_items)

Comment: I had the SET clause is in the wrong position, it belongs before the WHERE clause. I've modified the query, and it seems to work for me.